# How To Change WAMP 404 Page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, wamp

I'm setting up a Wamp Server, and i want to add a 404 page. I have tried creating a .htaccess file,and adding:

> ErrorDocument 404 /web/tools/404/index.html

, but when i mistype an address, it comes up with the normal Wamp 404.
I have my Wamp's port at 40, so i can bypass my ISP's block on port 80.
I can connect to my server from another computer, and it works perfectly,
accept for the 404. I can't post images, since i don't have enough reputation..

Comment: Add that to your vhost config instead, you may have it setup so it ignores htaccess.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: Your general syntax is correct, so the problem must be that the path `/web/tools/404/index.html` is not correct. This path is based on your `DocumentRoot` So check that `DocumentRoot/web/tools/404/index.html` is a valid folder structure.

Comment: Well, I have a drive called D:\ and in it is only my Wamp server,
So this is what it looks like:
D:/Wamp/www/web/tools/404/index.html.
The index.html does exist.
On the .htaccess file, do i put the D:/... etc.
@RiggsFolly